# How to evaluate special characters to see them in the text editor?

Tags: bash, text-processing

Let's say I have a text "line1\n\nline2\nline3" and I want to see it in a console or pipe it to a text editor so it looks like

```
line1

line2
line3
```

So special characters got evaluated.
Can I do it without regex replacing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use inline echo:

```
$ echo -e "line1\n\nline2\nline3"
line1

line2
line3
```

Answer (score 2):

Bash has a `printf` built-in, with support for `%b` to expand backslashes, and for `%q` to format a string so it can be used in shell commands without quotes (i.e., escape all characters that shells tend to treat specially with backslashes).

In other words, in Bash, you can use

```
printf '%b\n' 'line1\n\nline2\nline3'
```

to get

```
line1

line2
line3
```

If you don't want the newline following `line3`, use `printf '%b' 'line1\n\nline2\nline3'` instead.

The inverse (`%q`) is similarly useful,

```
printf '%q' '(foo $bar baz]'
```

outputting

```
\(foo\ \$bar\ baz\]
```

If you have a Bash variable containing a string with backslashes, e.g.

```
myvar='line1\n\nline2\nline3'
```

you can expand the escape sequences using

```
mytext=$(printf '%b' "$myvar")
```

If you just want to specify a literal string with escape sequences, use `$''`:

```
mytext=$'line1\n\nline2\nline3'
```